# 'Remaining Time: 5 days' then 'MySQL server has gone away' with Magento 2 data migration tool via Docker. How do I fix this?

Tags: database, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I'm using the Magento2 data-migration-tool from https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce to migrate a Magento 1.7.0.2 database to Magento 2.0.0.

I have successfully migrated settings.

When running the data migration, all the integrity checks pass, as you can see in the output below. However, when the tool reaches `[stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes step]`, the output announces `"Remaining Time: 5 days"` and does not progress past 0%.

Eventually the tool bombs out with `PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away`.

In an attempt to reduce the time estimate of 5 days, I imported the source database to the target mysql server.

Running SHOW PROCESSLIST on the Magento 2 database server while the tool is running shows no active processes.

There's not a lot of discussion around this tool available yet online. It would be very useful:

- to have some confirmation that people have successfully used this tool to migrate a Magento 1.x database to Magento 2.0.0
- to receive suggestions as to how I can speed up the import, or investigate what is causing it to hang

Here's the tool output from debug mode (with -vvv option), showing the point at which the tool hangs before bombing out:

```
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2015-12-09 09:24:10][DEBUG][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step][table: customer_entity]: migrating
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
```

Further information about my Magento 2 deployment:

- I'm using a docker-compose setup, with multiple docker containers for php-fpm, maria DB and app/data volumes, as per http://mageinferno.com/blog/magento-2-development-docker-os-x (but on Ubuntu)
- The Magento 2 installation works as expected, and after running the data migration tool's settings step my settings are used and available
- I'm running the data migration tool in a bash terminal started using docker exec.

It seems as if the docker setup might have something to do with this problem, although I haven't come across any issues during normal Magento 2 operation, or the settings step of the migration, which completes very quickly.

I've examined var/migration.log, which shows no further detail.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Have you cleaned your old database to ensure you are not bring extra unneeded data (Like the log tables)? How big is your original database that you are migrating?

Comment: Thanks. The imported DB size is 686 megabytes, according to the MySQL console. I don't think the log tables are being accessed at this point, but I've checked the number of rows in them and it isn't excessive. The database being migrated is a recent dump of an active and well-maintained production site, where the cron jobs keep things tidy.